# How to cat all lines together in file/for all files in a directory

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have 100's of files in a directory that contain lines of text. I want to concatenate all the lines in a file into a single line. I would like to do this for all files in a single pass. `cat` does not seem to work here

Example

File_1

```
atagacat
agataga
ctcatctat
tagcatag
```

File_1_cat

```
atagacatagatagactcatctattagcatag
```

File_2

```
atagacat
agataga
ctcatctat
tagcatag
```

File_2_cat

```
atagacatagatagactcatctattagcatag
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to add all the files in single file using cat?

Comment: No I want to concatenate all lines together into a single line for each file. I want to keep the files separate. The final product will be 100s of files with one line each. @ Raghvendra

Comment: ok. now i understand your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Simple `cat` + `tr` should be enough.
If not maybe something is wrong with your system:

```
sh-4.2$ cat file1 file2 
atagacat 
agataga 
ctcatctat 
tagcatag 
atagacat 
agataga 
ctcatctat 
tagcatag
sh-4.2$ cat file1 file2 |tr -d '\n'
atagacatagatagactcatctattagcatagatagacatagatagactcatctattagcatag
```

Test it online here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdUM4UER3SzE5Sk0

Update

After your clarification in comments that you need to remove new lines from each file separately and not join all files together (ps: don't put usefull clarifications in comments - edit your main question instead) , you can use something like :

```
perl -pe 's/\n//g' file >file_cat #perl -pe is directly equivalent to `sed`.
```

You can also use perl -pe to make batch replacements in more files at once:

```
perl -pe 's/\n//g' -i file{1..100) #-i : in-place replacements in each file
OR
perl -pe 's/\n//g' -i.bak file{1..100) #in-place replacement keeping also a backup of original file

ALSO this works for all txt files in a directory
perl -pe 's/\n//g' -i.bak *.txt #in line replacement of all txt files in current directory keeping also a back up file
```

You can offcourse use a kind of loop like mentioned in other answers or like this:

```
while IFS= -r -d '' fname;do 
  perl -pe 's/\n//g' "$fname" >"${fname}_cat"
  #any other command you might need like echo,cat,whatever
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file*' -print0)
```

Comment: The second bit is what the OP wants, but for each file separately.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeap, it was a clarification came in after my answer though. I will update.

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in ./*; do
  test -f "$name" && (tr -d '\n'; echo) <"$name" >"${name}_cat"
done
```

This will remove all newlines in all regular files (separately) in the current directory (this is what `tr -d '\n'` does).  The `echo` will make sure that there is a newline at the end of the line in each generated file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `tr` for that. `tr -d '\n'` removes **all** the newline characters. A non-empty file that has no newline character is not a text file. You need one newline character at the end for a sequence of characters to be considered as a proper line of text.

The canonical command to join all lines into a single one is the paste command:

```
 for file in ./*; do paste -sd '\0' "$file" > "${file}_cat"; done
```

That would do it for all the non-hidden files (regardless of their type -- regular, symlink, directory...) in the current directory. If there's no non-hidden file, in shells other than `zsh`, that would cause `paste` to give an error and create an empty `*_cat` file.

It would also create an empty `file_cat` files for files that can't be open. To avoid some of those problems, you may prefer:

```
for file in ./*; do
  [ ! -f "$file" ] || paste -sd '\0' - < "$file" > "${file}_cat"
done
```

instead (`-f` is to only consider regular files or  symlinks to regular files), or better and shorter with `zsh`:

```
file (./*(N-.)) do paste -sd '\0' - < $file > ${file}_cat
```

(add the `D` glob qualifier to include hidden files).

`-d '\0'` is the standard way to specify an empty separator (it does *not* mean a NUL character separator). Some `paste` implementations support `-d ''` for that as well, though that's not portable (other `paste` implementations would complain about the missing delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tr` in a loop, this way:

```
for file in *; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue  # skip if not a regular file
  printf "%s\n" $(tr -d '\n' < "$file") > "$file"_cat
done
```

The `\n` in `printf` makes sure that we do add a single newline at the end of the concatenated line.

Comment: A slight issue with this is if the file is immensely big.

Comment: Using the split+glob operator on the output of `tr` like that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
for i in file*; do
    awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*/, "");printf $0}' $i > ${i}_cat
done
```

where `gsub` does the following (cited from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)):

> gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])
>
> Search target for all of the longest, leftmost, nonoverlapping matching substrings it can find and replace them with replacement. The ‘g’ in gsub() stands for “global,” which means replace everywhere. For example:

```
{ gsub(/Britain/, "United Kingdom"); print }
```

> replaces all occurrences of the string ‘Britain’ with ‘United Kingdom’ for all input records.
>
> The gsub() function returns the number of substitutions made. If the variable to search and alter (target) is omitted, then the entire input record ($0) is used. As in sub(), the characters ‘&’ and ‘\’ are special, and the third argument must be assignable.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec perl -i -l -0777pe 'y/\n//d' {} +
```

. `find` picks up files from the current directory without recursing and hands them over to Perl in a bunch, which then goes ahead and strips them of newlines and stores back the changes within each file.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i -e '$!{N;s/^/\n/;D;};s/\n//g' {} +
```

Yet other methods to one-line a file is:

```
perl -i -lpe '$\ = eof ? "\n" : ""' yourfile
sed  -i -e   'H;$!d;g;s/\n//g'      yourfile

< yourfile sed 's/.*/[&]/' | dc -e '[[]pq]sq [?z0=q n z0=?]s? l?x'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{printf $0> (FILENAME"_cat")}' *
```

If you need new line at the end of new file:

```
awk '{printf $0> (FILENAME"_cat")}' *; sed -i -e '$a\' *_cat
```

Comment: The first argument of `printf` is the format, you must use `printf "%s", $0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim:

```
vim -Nesc 'bufdo! %j! | w %_cat' -c 'qa!' *
```

- `-Nesc <command>` is used to run `<command>` in non-compatible, silent ex-mode, which is useful for scripting Vim.
- `bufdo! <command>` runs the command on each buffer, not stopping for changed files
- `%j!` joins all lines without inserting any spaces (just `j` adds spaces), `%` being all lines in a range context
- `w %_cat` saves the current file to `<filename>_cat`, `%` being the current filename in a filename context
- `-c 'qa!'` then finally, close without saving all files.